# The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'X' already exists on table 'Y'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, constraints, primary-key

I am new to SQL and I have a SQL file and when I execute it the following error occurs:

> Msg 1913, Level 16, State 1, Line 463
>   The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'DDT_PK' already exists on table 'DAILY_DATA_TYPE'.

The error occurs when running this statement:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX DDT_PK 
    ON [DATE_DATA_TYPE]([TYPE_ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [DATE_DATA_TYPE] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DDT_PK] PRIMARY KEY ([TYPE_ID])
GO
```

I know that it already exists but I want to add a constraint and not create the index again so what am I doing wrong?

Maybe u have to know how the table was created too so here is the statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [DATE_DATA_TYPE] ([TYPE_ID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL,
[TYPE_NAME] [varchar](400) NOT NULL, [UNIT] [varchar](32) NOT NULL,
[CHART_TYPE] [varchar](32) NOT NULL, [RES_ID] [numeric](18, 0) NOT NULL)
GO
```

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Seems quite clear cut; use different names.

Comment: Your table doesn't match the table in the index scripts

Comment: you get the errors on `[DATE_DATA_TYPE]` however the table you gave us is `[DAILY_DATA_TYPE]`

Comment: oh sorry, I have changed it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Primary Key is automatically an `INDEX`. If you want to create a `NONCLUSTERED` Primary Key then use:

```
ALTER TABLE [DATE_DATA_TYPE]
ADD CONSTRAINT [DDT_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([TYPE_ID]);
```