# The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'XPKUSERS'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need help in understanding the error "The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'XPKUSERS'" and help in converting the query to TSQL

```
CREATE TABLE TDM_USERS_AUTH 
(
  USER_ROLE_ID VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL 
, ROLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
, USER_ID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL 
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX XPKUSERS ON TDM_USERS_AUTH (USER_ROLE_ID ASC);
ALTER TABLE TDM_USERS_AUTH
ADD CONSTRAINT XPKUSERS PRIMARY KEY 
(
  USER_ROLE_ID 
)
USING INDEX XPKUSERS;
```

> Msg 1913, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'XPKUSERS' already exists on table 'TDM_USERS_AUTH'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50911280/the-operation-failed-because-an-index-or-statistics-with-name-x-already-exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `USING INDEX` clause is a syntax specific to Oracle. In SQL Server, a new index is always created when you create a primary key. You can only choose if the new index is clustered (which is by default) or non-clustered.

You can simply create the PRIMARY KEY (without creating the index before), like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TDM_USERS_AUTH 
(
  USER_ROLE_ID VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL 
, ROLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
, USER_ID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL 
);
ALTER TABLE TDM_USERS_AUTH
ADD CONSTRAINT XPKUSERS PRIMARY KEY 
(
  USER_ROLE_ID 
);
```

You can also specify the primary key when creating the table:

```
CREATE TABLE TDM_USERS_AUTH 
(
  USER_ROLE_ID VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT XPKUSERS PRIMARY KEY 
, ROLE VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
, USER_ID VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL 
);
```